# Trouble mapping a function to a list of scraped links using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, mapping, rvest

I am trying to apply a function that extracts a table from a list of scraped links. I am at the final stage where I am applying the `get_injury_data` function to the links - I have been having issues with successfully executing this. I get the following error:

```
    Error in matrix(unlist(values), ncol = width, byrow = TRUE) : 
    'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I wonder if anyone can help me spot where I am going wrong. The code is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# create a function to grab the team links

get_team_links <- function(url){
  url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes('td.hauptlink a') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  .[. != '#'] %>% # remove rows with # string 
  paste0('https://www.transfermarkt.com', .) %>% # pat the website link to the url strings
  unique() %>% # keep only unique links
  as_tibble() %>% # turn strings into a tibble datatset
  rename("links" = "value") %>%  # rename the value column 
  filter(!grepl('profil', links)) %>% # remove link of players included 
  filter(!grepl('spielplan', links)) %>%  # remove link of additional team pages included
  mutate(links = gsub("startseite", "kader", links)) # change link to go to the  detailed page
}

# create a function to grab the player links
get_player_links <- function(url){
  url %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_nodes('td.hauptlink a') %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  .[. != '#'] %>% # remove rows with # string 
  paste0('https://www.transfermarkt.com', .) %>% # pat the website link to the url strings
  unique() %>% # keep only unique links
  as_tibble() %>% # turn strings into a tibble datatset
  rename("links" = "value")  %>%  # rename the value column 
  filter(grepl('profil', links)) %>% # remove link of players included
  mutate(links = gsub("profil", "verletzungen", links)) # change link to go to the injury page
}

# create a function to get the injury dataset
get_injury_data <- function(url){
  url %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('#yw1') %>%
  html_table()
}

# get team links and save it as team_links
team_links <- get_team_links('https://www.transfermarkt.com/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1')

# get player links and by mapping the function on to the player_injury_links dataset 
# and then unnest the list of lists as a long list
player_injury_links <- team_links %>% 
  mutate(links = map(team_links$links, get_player_links)) %>% 
  unnest(links)

# using the player_injury_links list create a dataset by web scrapping the play injury pages 
player_injury_data <- map(player_injury_links$links, get_injury_data)
```

Comment: have you tracked down which link is generating this error?

Comment: @QHarr No, not sure how best to do that.

Comment: @QHarr actually some players do not have injury data, so not sure how best to approach these players when creating html_table

Comment: wrap in tryCatch ?

Comment: @QHarr The error is still there.

Comment: FYI "scrapped" links would be discarded, thrown away like rubbish. You mean __scraped__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

So the issue that I was having was that some of the links that I was **scraping** did not have any data.

To overcome this issue used, I used the `possibly` function from `purrr` package. This helped me create a  new, error-free function.

The line code that was giving me trouble is as follows:

```
player_injury_data <-  player_injury_links %>%  
  purrr::map(., purrr::possibly(get_injury_data, otherwise = NULL, quiet = TRUE))
```